# Correct way to expand touchable area for a button - TouchDelegate vs Custom Button

Tags: android, listview, imagebutton

What is the correct (or perhaps most convenient) way to expand touchable areas of a button in a [listview](/questions/tagged/listview)?

When I first saw such expanded area in the Google Drive app, I though it is done using a custom button.

[image]

I was able to replicate this effect quite easily.

[image]

I used simple drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ff33B5E5" />            
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Just now I came across [touchdelegate](/questions/tagged/touchdelegate), which however seems like an overly complicated way for such an easy task. Are there any positives using TouchDelegates or is it just a matter of personal taste?

Comment: You're confusing the two notions. A `TouchDelegate` is supposed to extend the touch area of a view outside of that view's current area(to make it easier for the user to click on it, without actually making it bigger visually). With that drawable you just have a normal big button.

Comment: @Luksprog Yeah, you're right. I didn't see that in this particular example, as I didn't visually make it bigger. Anyways, thank you, I would accept it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `TouchDelegate` is a way to extend the touch area of a `View`(outside its current bounds) so it becomes easier for the user to act upon that widget(for example, it would make sense to extend the touch area of that star which is very small).

In the image you posted you have a simple `Button` for which a `TouchDelegate` doesn't make sense as it's big enough for the user to act upon.

Answer (score 0):

Have your button in a transparent relative layout or linearlayout.  make your button `android:clickable= false`  and layout `android:clickable= true`. so when you hit on the button , the layout will capture the click listener. now you can apply the drawable of the layout as your selector xml. you dont need a shape , just use a color and change it on state_pressed or state_focused or something like that.